# Validate string time range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, logic

I need to create a function to validate the following situation:

1. Monitored interval inside opening hours:
   [image: Valid]
2. Monitored interval outside opening hours:
   [image: Invalid]

There is another possibility that the allowed starting range is 23:00 to 04:00. In this case, ranges from 5:00 to 6:00 and 21:00 to 22:00 will not be allowed.

Currently my code validates the day normally, but the crossed day does not.

```
export default function isOutRangeStringTime({
  initialTime,
  finalTime,
  allowedInitialTime,
  allowedFinalTime,
}) {
  if (allowedInitialTime === allowedFinalTime
    || allowedInitialTime >= allowedFinalTime
    || initialTime >= finalTime) {
    return false;
  }
  return initialTime < allowedInitialTime || finalTime > allowedFinalTime;
}
```

Here's a picture of the situation that my code doesn't work.

1. crossed day Valid:
   [image: Crossday Valid]
2. crossed day invalid:
   [image]

I need validation to work for cross days too.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding 24h to allowedFinalTime when allowedFinalTime < allowedInitialTime

Consider using Date Objects.
For the sake of simplicity this example work with numbers:

```
function isOutRangeStringTime(
  initialTime,
  finalTime,
  allowedInitialTime,
  allowedFinalTime,
) {
  if (allowedInitialTime === allowedFinalTime
    || initialTime === finalTime) {
    return false;
  }
 if( allowedInitialTime > allowedFinalTime ) {
     allowedFinalTime += 24
     initialTime = (initialTime < allowedInitialTime) ? initialTime + 24 : initialTime;
     finalTime = (finalTime < allowedInitialTime) ? finalTime + 24 : finalTime;
 }

    return initialTime > allowedInitialTime && finalTime < allowedFinalTime;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try to simulate it with the data object, but using numbers like you said won't work. In some cases the values can be fractions of hours, for example: 15:45 - 19:20. Thank you, you offered me a new path

Comment: cast your strings as Date objects. Add 24h when allowedFinalTime < allowedInitialTime